# How to mix noise to "raw" file (AN4 database)

Tags: noise-reduction, sphinx4

I am doing a research in noise reduction. Could anyone tell me how to mix a noise file with an audio file? I am working with the AN4 database, so they are all in "raw" format.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a  noise file noise.wav and then mix it to an4 file with [sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/):

```
sox -m -r 16000 -s -2 file.raw noise.wav file_noise.wav
```

You can run sox in a loop to mix noise into all files

You can also mix white noise with sox dither command.